# Setting all DateTime fields to output microseconds

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am writing an API using django rest framework, and I have a models that contain datetime fields.

There are occasions where a field would have microseconds associated with it, and another field would not, the best example would be a **created** and an **start** field.
This is what the fields would look like being returned from the API:

```
created: "2015-09-17T16:30:50.732176Z"
start: "2015-09-03T06:10:00Z"
```

As you can see, microseconds are included in **created** but not in **start**.  Is there a setting I can set in django rest framework that would allow both both strings to be formatted the same?  Such that the output for these would be:

```
created: "2015-09-17T16:30:50.732176Z"
start: "2015-09-03T06:10:00.000000Z"
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a format parameter? See: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: I have looked at that, but I want it to affect all datetime fields in the project, so I don't have to add that to each field individually.

Comment: Have you considered subclassing `serializers`?

Comment: No I have not, could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to pass a format option for every `serializers.DateTimeField()` look into possible subclassing serializers.DateTimeField().

See the following example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar='baz'):
        self.bar = bar
        self.gub = 'gub'

class Footwo(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Footwo, self).__init__()
        self.bar='jib'


f = Foo()
ftwo = Footwo()
f.bar
ftwo.bar
```

This will print 'baz' and then 'jib'. So this logic should apply to serializers.DateTimeField() with something close to:

```
class FormattedDateTimeField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FormattedDateTimeField, self).__init__()
        self.format = 'My datetime format I want in all subclasses'
```

Resources:

[Subclassing with init args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840197/subclass-arguments-from-superclass)

[Python strtime format variables to use in your format](http://strftime.org/)